# WLAN and function keys stopped working, phy0 hard blocked

Tags: iwlwifi, function-keys, ideapad

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 3, and have been running single boot KDE Neon (20.04 focal) for years. Yesterday my desktop froze. Upon reboot, I found myself with no touchpad, no function keys (with the exception of the Volume keys that continued to work), and no WLAN.

Except the Function keys, there are no other keys on my laptop that can control hardware.

According to the BIOS, WLAN as well as Function keys are enabled.

I disabled the **ideapad_laptop** module with `modprobe -r` and by blacklisting in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` which briefly got the WLAN working. At this point, I updated my sources and upgraded my packages. Upon reboot, I found that my WLAN was now *once again not working*, but *touchpad is working*.

Further experimentation with the **ideapad_laptop** module yielded no results. Disabling it removes the *ideapad_wlan* and *ideapad_bluetooth* entries from `rfkill list`, leaving *hci0* Bluetooth and *phy0* WLAN. This has no effect on Bluetooth functionality. As per the title, phy0 is hard blocked. As expected, `rfkill unblock all` does not change this.

The `lshw -c network` command tells me that I have an Intel **Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth** network controller, and the `lspci` command tells me that my Kernel module and driver in use is **iwlwifi**.

I've tried running Arch and Neon live from USB, but *phy0*  continues to be hard blocked, and no function keys. Any thoughts?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.    *FYI:   KDE Neon does share a number of support options common with Kubuntu, alas this is not one of them with Neon off-topic here*